# grep after matching pattern but exclude period

Tags: sed, grep, matching

I have the following sample strings:

```
Program exiting with code: 0.
Program exiting with code: 1.
Program exiting with code: 10.
```

I want grep to return values after the matching pattern "Program exiting with code:". However I do not need the period at the end. I have tried:

```
grep "Program exiting with exit code:" dataload.log | sed 's/^.*.: //'
```

The above command returns:

```
0.
1.
10.
```

I want to ignore the period at end. I picked up the above command from somewhere.

Can someone describe what each keyword represents and provide me with a regex that will only provide me with the value without period?

`sed`, `awk`, `perl` or any other way is fine with me.

Comment: This is how my working snippet looks like now after using the solution provided by @AdamTaylor
http://pastebin.com/dJ4Mydz2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/^.*.: //'
```

First of all this is a substition regular expression, as denoted by the `s` at the start. The part in the first `/ /` is what to match and the second `/ /` is what to replace it with.

The characters in the first (match) part of the expression are all special regular expression characters.

A full list of what they mean can be found here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

The match means:

`^` - At the start of the line

`.` - Match any character

`*` - Any number of times

`.` - Match any character

`:` - Match a colon

- Match a space

And then that is all replaced with nothing. That is why the period at the end is kept because it removes everything up to `Program exiting with code:`, which leaves `1.`

It's worth playing around with an interactive tool to test different regular expressions on your string, e.g. http://www.regexr.com/

You can probably just substitute/remove everything that is not a number in your case: `'s/[^0-9]//g'`.

Comment: Good that you explain why it does not work. However, the suggested approach is a bit fragile since it does not check that the number should be after `Program exiting with code: `.

Comment: There are lots of way you could do it. And, true, what I suggested could cause false matches if all the output doesn't match the example given. Here's another solution with a match group: `sed 's/Program exiting with code: \([0-9]*\)\./\1/'`

Comment: There's also another problem: lines that do not start with `Program exiting ...` will be left untouched.

Comment: @AdamTaylor, thanks for your detailed explanation. the regex 's/[^0-9]//g' does work for me well and is fine as per my current requirement as this is how the string is going to be always in my file. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use grep with a look-behind and catch only digits:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Program exiting with code: )\d*' file
0
1
10
```

Comment: @KiranSavadatti it works with a GNU grep and the input you provided. Update your question with a description of the grep version you use.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way:

```
grep -oE 'Program exiting with code:\s*[0-9]+' dataload.log |grep -oE '[0-9]+$'
```

Output of the first grep command is:

```
Program exiting with code: 0
Program exiting with code: 1
Program exiting with code: 10
```

Then you just `grep` the last digits.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is just fine if you extend it with a `cut` command:

`grep "Program exiting with code:" dataload.log | sed 's/^.*.: //' | cut -d"." -f1`

Comment: what was the purpose of down voting it? I have just pointed out and extension to the OP's own solution and it works.